# What should the FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, content, on-off-topic

While this will evolve within the next week or two as questions are populated, it's something we need to begin thinking about.

Obviously questions about the following things are on topic:

- Raspberry Pi Hardware
- Raspberry Pi Software

However, a lot of content shares scope with other sites.  What specific subjects should the FAQ contain as on or off-topic?

Comment: This should be made Community Wiki.

Comment: Community wiki answer added.

Comment: Since cases are more than aesthetic, would this question be on topic? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/337/35

Comment: @BryanDunsmore do we have an FAQ yet? (For Meta)

Comment: @xxmbabanexx There really isn't a faq for meta.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about the following things are on-topic:

- The Raspberry Pi hardware.
- Raspberry Pi peripherals.
- Software that runs on the Raspberry Pi.
- Operating systems that run on the Raspberry Pi.

Questions about the following things are off-topic:

- The ordering and/or purchasing of the Raspberry Pi.
- Any accessories relating exclusively to appearance.

Comment: What's the consensus on unspecific OS questions?

Comment: @Jivings It seems to be split pretty even. http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24/raspberry-pi-itself-vs-specific-os-issues