# Pointing to the Foundation on the RaspPi.SE Homepage

Tags: support, foundation

Given the fact the RaspPi foundation are supporting their forum as the official resource, can we support their work further by linking to them somehow on the front page?

i.e. https://askubuntu.com/ has the 'Welcome' widget on the front page to the top right above the community meta details. And tags also have drop down details explaining them when their searched.

Could either be adopted here to help direct people to work of the foundation on their site/forum and clearly distinguish that the forum is the officially sanctioned resource and we're just a bunch of do-gooders from the community? :)

This should help alleviate concerns of competition between the SE community effort and the RaspPi forum.

See also;
[Stack Exchange site vs. forum](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/stack-exchange-site-vs-forum), 
[How can we gain support of the Raspberry Pi foundation?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-we-gain-support-of-the-raspberry-pi-foundation), [Promoting the site on forums](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/promoting-the-site-on-forums)

Answer (score 6):

Ask Ubuntu is a part of a special partnership with the company behind Ubuntu, [Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/).

While this site is in beta, it's unlikely that we'd form a similar partnership with the Raspberry Pi Foundation, although it's certainly not out of the question in the future. We can explore that as the site grows and gets closer to graduation.

So, we can't put a link to the Foundation on the front page at this point, but we can certainly add it to the [FAQ](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq). You guys already have [a question about figuring out what goes into the FAQ](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-the-faq-contain), so I suggest bringing up the link to the Foundation and specific wording there.

Last but not least, far as tags go, you (as the community here in general) can edit tag wikis to include any links you think are relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I like it - I think anything we can do to try to genuinely show we're not competing and undermining their work is a good thing.

Comment: To avoid competing, we should also be stricter about what kind of questions are considered on-topic.  There is a lot of overlap at the moment, which they may see as competition.

Comment: @finnw This is a site about their product, there is going to be **a lot** of overlap.